# Change Lang while runtime

Tags: java, android

this is my Change lang Function

```
public static String currectLang = "distance";

public static void changeLang(Activity a)
{

    if(currectLang.equals("distance"))
    {
        currectLang ="iw";

    }
    else
    {
        currectLang = "distance";
    }
    Resources res = a.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(new Locale(currectLang)); // API 17+ only.
    // Use conf.locale = new Locale(...) if targeting lower versions
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);


}
```

}

and this is the MainActivity:

```
Button lang,caller,music,media;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //change lang Button
    lang = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLang);
    lang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Func.changeLang(MainActivity.this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MainActivity.this.recreate();
        }
    });

    //Move to Caller Activity Button
    caller = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCaller);
    caller.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

    //Move to Caller Activity Button
    music = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMusic);
    music.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

    //Move to Caller Activity Button
    media = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMedia);
    media.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    Intent moveActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CallerActivity.class);
    switch(id)
    {
        case R.id.btnCaller:
            moveActivity.setClass(MainActivity.this,CallerActivity.class);
            break;

        case R.id.btnMedia:
            moveActivity.setClass(MainActivity.this,CallerActivity.class);
            break;

        case R.id.btnMusic:
            moveActivity.setClass(MainActivity.this,CallerActivity.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(moveActivity);
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;



}
```

}

and i have second activity that run the same changelang function
the problem is that the Activitys dont update their lang, if i use the function on one activty, the lang in the other stay. how can i fix it?

Comment: Why are you calling `setContentView` a second time?

Comment: after change locale should start new instance of activity, do you test it?

Comment: @cricket_007 i have no idea, i removed it from my code, thanks you :)

Comment: @Saeed-rz im pretty new for Android studio, what do u mean?

Comment: @Saeed-rz Did you miss `MainActivity.this.recreate();`?